# How to verify this isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be $\mathbb{R}^2/\langle(1,2)\rangle$ and $\mathbb{R}$ .These two vector spaces have the same dimension $(\dim=1)$, then there is a theorem that ensures that they are isomorphic, but my question is what is that isomorphism and how to find it? thank you very much, I'm new in this topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are more than one isomorphism, so if you want to find one in particular you can choose $\{(1,0),(1,2)\}$ as a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then a basis for the quotient is $[(1,0)]$ and an isomorphism is given by the linear map sending $ [(1,0)]\longmapsto 1\in \mathbb{R}$, where we have choose $1$ as a basis for $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would the explicit form of the linear transformation T? $T([x,y])=x$?

Comment: No, the map is $T([x,y])=\frac{2x-y}{2}$, infact every element in the class of $[1,2]$ is sent to zero.

Comment: So this map is an isomorphism from the quotient space to R.

Comment: thanks again, but how do you do to determine T? Can you explain please?

Comment: Is not very easy without a picture. However I suggest you to draw in the real plane the equivalent class, which are a sheaf of parallel straight line in the plane. In particular the unique line passing through the origin is associate to the class $[1,2]$. Then using some trigonometry properties you find T.

Comment: I have calculated  line to the equivalence class of $[1,2]$, are $y=2x$, and I calculated the same for the point $[1,1]$ are $y=2x-1$, both lines are clearly parallel, but how to use trigonometry to find a general form of T? I'm sorry, I do not understand much... =(

Comment: Let $l$ any line in he sheaf, and $p$ a point belong to it, then you have to find a linear function the associate $p$ to the intersection of $l$ with the $x$-axis.

Comment: Thanks, I've found another way to find $T$, but I used linear combinations of the bases and I was effective. Now I have problems in verifying the injectivity and surjectivity of $T$. Because I tried to find the kernel but by solving the equation $\frac{2x-y}{2}=0$ does not throw me the zero vector of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If you prove the injectivity, the surjectivity follow since they have the same dimension.

Comment: I have serious doubts as to find the kernel and the image of T, could you please explain? and excuse me =(

Comment: Don't worry: try to answer to this question: which couples solve the equation $2x-y=0$? Clearly there a lot of couples, but all of these belong to...to which class? ;) consider that $[1,2]$ has to be consider as 0 in the quotient.

Comment: I have already captured, that is, all couples that satisfy the equation belong to the class $[1,2]$, then $ker(T)=[1,2]=[0,0]$ is this correct?. How I can verify that the image is $\mathbb{R}$? I guess besides all this must verify that $T$ is well defined...

Comment: Crearly $T$ is well defined, but you can check it. Your answer is correct. Now you have done, since they have same dimension injectivity implies surjectivity. Then it is an isomorphism.

Comment: To check the good definition, I did the following: Let be $[a,b],[c,d]\in\mathbb{R}^2/\langle(1,2)\rangle$ such that $[a,b]=[c,d]$ iff $(a,b)-(c,d)\in \langle(1,2)\rangle$ iff $(a-c,b-d)=(k,2k)$ with $k\in \mathbb{R}$ iff $a-c=k$ and $b-d=2k$, I multiplied the first equation by $-2$and plunges to the second and got it $-2a+b+2c-d=0$, I cleared the first member and multiplied on both sides of the equation by $-1/2$and i got $\frac{2a-b}{2}=\frac{2c-d}{2}$ iff $T[a,b]=T[c,d]$ What I did is right?

Comment: It's perfect! :)

Comment: Thank you so much Gianluca, you are awesome!!! =) Greetings from Venezuela.

Answer (score 2):

Complete a basis for $\mathbb R^2$ with $(-2,1)$.

Then $(x,y) \mapsto -2x+y$ is a linear map $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ with kernel $\langle(1,2)\rangle$.

This map is the orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal complement of $\langle(1,2)\rangle$.

The induced map $\mathbb{R}^2/\langle(1,2)\rangle \to \mathbb R$ is $(x,y) \bmod \langle(1,2)\rangle \mapsto -2x+y$. (Make sure you understand that this map is well defined.)

Comment: But the domain must be $\mathbb{R}^2/\langle(1,2)\rangle$ not $\mathbb{R}^2$  How would the explicit form of the linear transformation T?

Comment: @DanielaRondón, see my edited answer.

Comment: Sorry what does it mean $(x,y) \bmod \langle(1,2)\rangle$?